# No method parse for String

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust by following the [official guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html).

However, I received an error regarding a `String` not implementing the `parse` method. I've searched the docs and found the method [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.parse).

For my peace of mind, I would like to know if there's an issue with the guide (quite likely for pre 1.0 language) or if I'm doing something wrong.

Rust version:

rustc 0.13.0-nightly (34d680009 2014-12-22 00:12:47 +0000)

I've copied the code and error bellow.

```
use std::io;
use std::rand;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = (rand::random::<uint>() % 100u) + 1u;

    println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let input = io::stdin().read_line()
                           .ok()
                           .expect("Failed to read line");
    let input_num: Option<uint> = input.parse();

    let num = match input_num {
        Some(num) => num,
        None      => {
            println!("Please input a number!");
            return;
        }
    };


    println!("You guessed: {}", num);

    match cmp(num, secret_number) {
        Less    => println!("Too small!"),
        Greater => println!("Too big!"),
        Equal   => println!("You win!"),
    }
}

fn cmp(a: uint, b: uint) -> Ordering {
    if a < b { Less }
    else if a > b { Greater }
    else { Equal }
}
```

Compiling, it raises the following:

> /home/daniel/Projects/guessing_game/src/main.rs:16:41: 16:48 error:
>   type `collections::string::String` does not implement any method in
>   scope named `parse` /home/daniel/Projects/guessing_game/src/main.rs:16
>   let input_num: Option = input.parse();

Comment: This code works fine as-is with `rustc 0.13.0-dev (29ad8539b 2014-12-24 16:21:23 +0000)`. You may want to update your rustc to match the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a question of `rustc` versions: the `parse` method [was added ~2 days ago](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19741), but your compiler is about 3 days old. Rust moves fast and it's easy to hit little cases like this when working at the bleeding edge unfortunately.

Hopefully this will really start to settle from [the 9th of January](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2014/12/12/1.0-Timeline.html).

Comment: Well, that was certainly bad luck. I've reinstalled rust and it works!